# 拡張アプリ（Enterprise版のChromeBook）のデバッグ方法

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

拡張アプリの開発中です。
ChromeBook上のChromeブラウザのデベロッパーツールでデバッグを実施したいのですが、デベロッパーツールが開きません。

通常の拡張アプリと違う点は以下の通りです。
・ChromeBookがEnterprise版として、GoogleWorkSpaceで管理されています。
・GoogleWorkSpaceに拡張アプリを登録して、登録されているChromeBookに自動的にインストールしています。
・chrome.enterprise.platformKeysというAPIを利用するのでGoogleWorkSpaceからインストールする必要があります。
　（そうしないと上記のAPIが利用できないとエラーが出るためです）
　ですので、ローカルからChromeBookのブラウザに拡張アプリをインストールする方法は利用できないのです。

質問の内容なのですが、
chromeブラウザの拡張機能ページで「ビューを検証」とう欄に、バックグラウンドページを表示する方法を
ご存じの方がいましたらお教えください。

（enterprise版としてでなく、ローカルからインストールするとエラーは出ますが「ビューを検証」にバックグラウンドページが表示されます。）

enterpriseとしてインストールされるとアイコンにオレンジ色のビルのマークが右下に表示されるので
通常の拡張アプリとのインストールとは違う様です。

この欄に表示されればデバッグが出来そうなのですけれども、ポリシーや manifest.json を色々と修正しても表示できない状態です。

他に必要な情報がありましたら仰ってください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

Chromeのポリシーでデベロッパーツールの設定が下記に設定されていたのが原因でした。
「自動インストールされた拡張機能を除き常に組み込みのデベロッパー ツールの使用を許可する」

GoogleWorkspaceの拡張アプリ毎のポリシーで「自動インストール」を設定している場合、
上記の条件によりデベロッパーツールの使用が出来なくなっていました。

上記の設定から下記の設定へ変更したところ、使用できるようになりました。
「常に組み込みのデベロッパー ツールの使用を許可する」

どなたかの参考になれば幸いです。